# Comparator doesn't sort correctly

Tags: java, comparator

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList containing TurnChoices (I will show the code of this class). So I created a class that implements Comparator https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

compare method is supposed to return -1,0,1 as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second, right? I am trying to understand why my ArrayList has the lower TurnChoice on the first index. I could replace 1 by -1 and -1 by 1 but this wouldn't respect what the documentation says and I want to understand what is wrong.

TurnChoiceComparater class:

```
package pkmnVerDemacia.battle.turn;

import java.util.Comparator;

import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.turn.item.UseItemChoice;
import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.turn.swap.SwapChampionChoice;
import pkmnVerDemacia.model.champion.Champion;
import pkmnVerDemacia.model.champion.stat.STAT;

public class TurnChoiceComparater implements Comparator<TurnChoice>
{

    @Override
    public int compare(TurnChoice tc1, TurnChoice tc2)
    {
        if (tc1.getPriority() > tc2.getPriority())
            return 1;
        else if (tc1.getPriority() == tc2.getPriority()) {
            return compareChampSpeed(tc1.getChampionUser(), tc2.getChampionUser());
        }
        else
            return this.getRandomSort();
    }
    
    private int compareChampSpeed(Champion c1, Champion c2) {
        if (c1.getStat(STAT.SPEED) > c2.getStat(STAT.SPEED)) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (c1.getStat(STAT.SPEED) < c2.getStat(STAT.SPEED)) {
            System.out.println(c2.getName()+" is faster than "+c1.getName()+" so I return -1");
            System.out.println("first TurnChoice has Champion: "+c1.getName());
            System.out.println("second TurnChoice has Champion: "+c2.getName());
            return -1;
        }
        else
            return this.getRandomSort();
    }
    
    private int getRandomSort() {
        double random = Math.random();
        if (random > 0.5)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }
}
```

Here TurnChoice class

```
package pkmnVerDemacia.battle.turn;

import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.BATTLE_PARTY;
import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.Battle;
import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.event.BattleEvent;
import pkmnVerDemacia.battle.event.BattleEventQueuer;
import pkmnVerDemacia.model.champion.Champion;

public abstract class TurnChoice
{
    protected BattleEventQueuer beQueuer;
    
    protected BATTLE_PARTY userParty;
    
    protected int priority;
    
    public TurnChoice(BattleEventQueuer beQueuer, BATTLE_PARTY userParty, int priority) {
        this.beQueuer = beQueuer;
        this.userParty = userParty;
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    
    public int getPriority()
    {
        return this.priority;
    }

    public BATTLE_PARTY getUserParty() {
        return this.userParty;
    }
    
    public BattleEventQueuer getBEQueuer() {
        return this.beQueuer;
    }
    
    public Champion getChampionUser() {
        return this.beQueuer.getChampion(this.userParty);
    }

    public abstract boolean begin();
}
```

And here is where I test the code:

```
public static void sortTurnChoices(ArrayList<TurnChoice> choices)
{
    Collections.sort(choices, new TurnChoiceComparater());
    for (TurnChoice choice : choices)
        System.out.println(choice.getChampionUser().getName());
}
```

Console result here:

[image]

As you can see Vi is faster than Braum so why Braum is at the first index of the ArrayList?

Comment: `return this.getRandomSort();` - looks "suspicious at best" in *any* compare path (ordering "should be stable"). Anyway, by the print output displayed, the ordering is "correct" as cmp(Braum's speed, Vi's speed) returned -1 so Braum "comes before" Vi.

Comment: This shouldn't compile as `getStat` is not defined.

Comment: FWIW: I bet the 'confusion' will go away when writing `System.out.println(c2.getName()+" is faster than "+c1.getName()+" so I return -1");` using the *same logic* as the `<`: `System.out.println("First 
 (" + c1.getName() + ") is SLOWER THAN Second (" + c2.getName() + ") so I return -1");` It is valid because `x2 > x1` ~ `x1 < x2`.

Comment: if it returns -1 then why Braum is  at the first index? getStat is defined on Champion class

Comment: ..because -1 (any value < 0) from `compare` means "a **smaller than** b" or  "a **comes first/before** b". Like 0, 1, 2.. 9. `compare(1,2) < 0`, `compare(9,1) > 0`, `compare(3,3) == 0`. Consider that this allows the ordering of any two values that can be treated as integers: `compare(x,y)` ~same "compare" equivalency as~ `y - x`.

Comment: awwww my bad i thought it sorts from the bigger to the smaller thank you

Comment: Anyway, if there were my code I would remove the randomness from the primary sort and do it this way: step 1) group actions by priority (no randomness, stable sort) 2) iterate by priority-group 3) if there are multiple actions in each priority group, do random selection only within the group. This pulls out the unstable sort/order/selection to a very specific location.